# Notepad++ How do I delete the brackets and the text in between?

Tags: notepad++

I would like to turn this:

53
00:04:25,474 --> 00:04:26,642
ah. Here you are.

54
00:04:26,934 --> 00:04:27,810
[speaking Chinese]

55
00:04:28,185 --> 00:04:29,603
[speaking Chinese]

56
00:04:30,145 --> 00:04:31,939
[speaking Chinese]

57
00:04:32,022 --> 00:04:33,107
[speaking Chinese]

58
00:04:33,524 --> 00:04:35,442
This is my friend, Dr. Gerard.

Into this:

53
00:04:25,474 --> 00:04:26,642
ah. Here you are.

54
00:04:26,934 --> 00:04:27,810

55
00:04:28,185 --> 00:04:29,603

56
00:04:30,145 --> 00:04:31,939

57
00:04:32,022 --> 00:04:33,107

58
00:04:33,524 --> 00:04:35,442
This is my friend, Dr. Gerard.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h*\[.+\]\h*`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\[          # openning bracket
.+          # 1 or more any character
\]          # closing bracket
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I typically use ^ to match the beginning of a line and $ to match the end, and then search for something in between. eg: `(^.+?)\[.+\](.+?$)` and replace that with `$1 $2` but this works just as well.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to mark this answer as solved, so others know you no longer need help.

Comment: @LPChip: The less capture groups you have, the more efficient the regex is.

Comment: That's true. Just goes to show how I default to a certain thinking method when dealing with regex.